# which of these is the proper way to do error handling

Tags: go

I'm in the situation where I have a function which can return up to 5 different errors, but I'm not sure which is considered correct by convention in Go. I've made a small MSVC example below to illustrate my issue.

Use the if syntax to block scope my errors.

```
if err := validatePassword(password); err != nil {
    return err
}

if passwordHash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

OR name each err differntly (seems cumbersome...)

```
errValidatePassword := validatePassword(password)
if errValidatePassword != nil {
    return errValidatePassword
}

passwordHash, errPasswordHash := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
if errPasswordHash != nil {
    return errPasswordHash
}
```

OR use a named return.

```
func registerAccount(email string, password string) (err error) {

    err = validatePassword(password)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // POSSIBLE ISSUE HERE as err already been inistalised????
        passwordHash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good question to ask while coding, but there's no single perfect answer. In general, handling errors in place like method 1 or method 3 is common practice in Go.

You may refer https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The last example is what I've seen in most places. e.g. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cmd/genutils/genutils.go

The compiler will not detect that as redefinition because the expression has at least one new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Given last example, One solution is to not not use named return variable, and to introduce scopes for each functional blocks

```
package main

func registerAccount(email string, password string) error {

    if err := validatePassword(password); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var passwordHash []byte
    {
        x, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        passwordHash = x
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note that the if already scopes the variable if you take full advantage of its syntax.